# What should be my move as white and what kind endgame should i target?

Tags: endgame, strategy, counterplay

[image: the chess game]

I played this game with an AI. I played brilliantly till this position presented itself.

Comment: So many games I played brilliantly until I didn't know what to do...

Comment: Your best move is to resign.  There is no way you can defend the f4 pawn and once Black breaks through there it is all over.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo how about queen to B3

Comment: Since black is way ahead in material -- B+N v 2P -- my first move candidate would be to ignore the threat and play Qxh4, and see if the penetration from the R+Q would come home before your queen sortie could amount to anything. If I decided against it, then Nd5 would be my second candidate. Honestly, with two extra pieces, black is sitting comfortably. Black's goal is a breakthrough with the Q at h4, N posted to d5 (and if chased, just take the f4 pawn) Rooks on f8 and f5, and the King tucked away safely on h7 and White will be mated soon. No endgame in sight.

Comment: Note: I encourage others to not downvote/discourage others to downvote. Consider that this question is heavily downvoted but that https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33959/why-is-this-a-checkmate is heavily upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Lichess: [1r1q2k1/1p4b1/1n2p1p1/p3Pr1p/P2PRP1P/R1P5/1P6/3Q2K1 w - - 0 1](https://lichess.org/analysis/standard/1r1q2k1/1p4b1/1n2p1p1/p3Pr1p/P2PRP1P/R1P5/1P6/3Q2K1_w_-_-_0_1)

There's not really any hope here unless black is down a lot of time, and there's no increment or something.

White is down 2 pawns for 2 minor pieces. Maybe just 1 pawn for a minor piece is a little manageable but when it's 2 for 2, nothing really to be done.

Theoretically though, I wouldn't mind playing king and 2 pawns vs king, bishop and knight.